# Fixed visible height value on dynamic header images

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I've got a Wordpress-site where the users can choose to upload different header images to any specific post or page they create. In happy cases the header image looks good as the height does not take up the entire page. However, **I want to set a maximum visible height value to the header image, such as 350px, so that the rest of the image gets hidden or 'cut off' from the content that follows.** Using the css max-height property only makes the image shrink in an ugly way, as the length of it needs to be 100%.

I tried wrapping the image in a div with a fixed height and then using overflow: hidden on the image, which did not work. Then I tried using z-index to make the content cover the overflowing part of the image, without any success.

Any ideas of how to get around this issue?

Comment: Here check the e.g: Image height is 120 and header height I kept is 100px
http://jsfiddle.net/vinayak5192/dnot8k9c/

Comment: @Cia please provide code that make us to understand your problem easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I kept the height of your .site-header div to 200px

[image]

Comment: Cool! So the trick is to set the containing div to a fixed height and with an overflow as hidden, and not the image itself. I am forever grateful :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use Overflow css property. 
IF the image height is more than xx height the rest of image will get hidden.

e.g :  [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/vinayak5192/dnot8k9c/)

```
.header {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100px;
     overflow: hidden; 
}
```

Comment: It should work, but for some reason the image still gets shrunk and there is no overflow. Here's a screencap: http://i.imgur.com/MA6TOuj.png Have I missed something in the code? The divs around the image don't have any height values.

Comment: The Div you are inserting Image dynamically should have some height , Then Only It will hide the image extra part. 
refer to my e.g I have give height to my header, because of it image hides after 100px;

Comment: DO you have your site live ? Give me link I will check.

Comment: Yeah... I inserted this awfully big header image just to try fixing it: http://designbycia.com/billdalsridklubb/kontakt/

Comment: How much Height header image you need ? This seems to be slider section image if i'm not wrong.

Comment: I think 350px would look great. It doesn't matter so much though, as long as I am able to control and have the same height on all uploaded header images. How do you mean by slider section? The header is supposed to be static...

Answer (score 1):

If you are not constrained to use a img tag, you can set the image as a background:

HTML

```
<div id="site-header" style="background-image: url('<?php header_image(); ?>')"> 
  <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home">

  </a> 
</div>
```

CSS

Setting background-size to cover, makes the image to cover the entire div.

```
#site-header{
  height:350px;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
#site-header a{
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

Comment: It would be awesome if that worked, but unfortunately the image pops up as an img-tag. Here's the code that generates the header image:  `<div id="site-header">
  <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
   <img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>">
  </a>
 </div>`

Answer (score 0):

Use your image as background for div and set that property:

```
background-size: 100%;
```